# Trouble writing data in an excel file accordingly

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, xlsxwriter

I'm very new to work with `xlsxwriter` in python. I have created a scraper in python and it is working flawlessly. However, when I try to write these data in an excel file using `xlsxwriter` I get stuck. What I have written so far can create an excel file and write the last populated data derived from the for loop. How can I rectify my script to write all the data rather than the last one. It would be better If i knew how to append the newly populated values on the fly.

The bottom line is, I'm getting two issues:

1. My script writes only the last populated values
2. The two fields are being written in a line, as in `row("A1"), row("A2")` but I wish to have them like `row("A1"), row("B1")` and so on.

Script I've tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xlsxwriter

row = 0
col = 0

with xlsxwriter.Workbook('torrent.xlsx') as workbook:
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
        res = s.get("https://www.yify-torrent.org/search/1080p/")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
        for item in soup.select(".mv"):
            name = item.select("a")[0].text
            link = item.select("a")[0]['href']
            data = name , link

    for elem in data:
        worksheet.write(row, col, elem)
        row += 1
```

The result I'm having like (in a line):

```
title
link
```

Whereas, I wish to have them like (in separate rows):

```
title link
title1 link1
title2 link2
```

and so on.

Answer (score 2):

1. Each time through the first `for` loop, you overwrite `data`, so only the last thing assigned survives.  This could be addressed by moving your second `for` loop to be inside the first, so it gets called for each value of `data`.
2. If you want things to be in different columns, you need to use different values for `col` when you call `worksheet.write`.  You use `row += 1` to advance to subsequent rows; `col += 1` would do the same for columns.

Comment: Thanks @Scott Hunter for your suggestion. I searched a lot but could not find any appropriate guideline to proceed. Would you be kind enough to give a little demo as to how? Thanks again.

Comment: @Topto: Why don't you take a crack at it and come back if you have any other, specific questions?

Answer (score 0):

As Scott Hunter noted, your overwriting your data, which is stored just fine as a tuple in your data variable.  However, it seems like your issue is in your for loop, where you're only adding to row within each block, which explains why your code is traveling only vertically in your spread sheet.  Perhaps rearranging things and adding in an iterator could help?

```
for idx,elem in enumerate(data):
    worksheet.write(row, idx, elem)
    row += 1
```

Enumerate function will consistently add 1 to the idx variable for every iteration of code, therefor this single block of code can extend as far out as your tuple of data is long.

Hope this helps!